# Query to fetch records received in last 24 hrs based on timestamp on file name

Tags: sql

I am using SQl pro. I want to fetch the records which were received in last 24 hrs from the table. Lets consider table name = INVENTORY, containing 4 columns, COL1, COL2, COL3 and File_Name. There is is no any date column in the table. But the File_Name column will always have data in the format ABC_03_20180412_053028.txt. (ABC_03_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt). I want to know how to fetch the records for the table which were received in last 24hrs using the date and time from the file name.

Comment: Did you try something to get the desired result?

Comment: SQLPro is an *interface*.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havenot tagged the DB that you are using, im trying to give a generic answer.

Assuming that the filename column follows similar pattern to 'ABC_03_20180412_053028.txt', you can try to parse the file_name column this way,

```
select (split_part('ABC_03_20180412_053028.txt', '_',3) || ' ' ||
left(split_part('ABC_03_20180412_053028.txt', '_',4),6))::timestamp;
```

This will return the timestamp as,

```
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2018-04-12 05:30:28
```

Try this to fetch the one day interval,

```
select (split_part('ABC_03_20180412_053028.txt', '_',3) || ' ' ||
left(split_part('ABC_03_20180412_053028.txt', '_',4),6))::timestamp 
+ '24 hours' :: interval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would extract the string and cast to a date.  This depends on the database, but I am going to guess you are using MySQL.  If, you can use `str_to_date()` like this:

```
str_to_date(substring(filename, 7, 15), '%Y%m%d_%h%i%s')
```

The comparison for the most recent 24 hours is:

```
str_to_date(substring(filename, 7, 15), '%Y%m%d_%h%i%s') >= now() - interval 24 hour and
str_to_date(substring(filename, 7, 15), '%Y%m%d_%h%i%s') < now()
```

The second part is probably not necessary, because files probably do not have future dates.

Comment: Thanks to all. It is very help full.